# sourcemap of concatenated javascript files doesn't map anymore

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I serve a complex js file that is the concatenation of several other JS files:

```
//file1.min.js 
...

//file2.min.js
...
//# sourceMappingURL=file2.min.js.map  

//file3.min.js 
...
```

As you can see, file2.min.js has a sourcemap generated by webpack, the other files don't have one (and I don't care to have one).

Of course if I serve the single files alone, browsers can attach to the sourcefile, but when I concatenate the files like this it doesn't work anymore.

I don't really understand what to do to make it work. Should I have to regenerate a new sourcemap for the whole file, even if I only have a part of the original sourcemaps?

Or do I have to fix something in the sourcemap that I already have?

I have not studied the sourcemap spec enough to understand what I have to do. Any help would be appreciated.